# How to join result table with existing table, on repeating values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to Join result table if the emp_id is repeated. and display employees first name.

result table code:

```
SELECT emp_id, COUNT(*)
FROM Employment
GROUP BY emp_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Employment table:

| emp_id | task_complete | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **task1** | 2020 |
| **1** | **task2** | 2020 |
| 3 | task3 | 1999 |
| 4 | task4 | 2001 |

Employee table:

| emp_id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jon | Doe |
| 2 | Don | Juan |
| 3 | Steve | Works |
| 4 | Loki | Odinsen |

So that employee 1 has done 2 tasks, Result should look like:

| emp_id | first_name | tasks_done |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jon | 2 |

Comment: So if you want, you should just join. What is the issue with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like `group by` and `having`:

```
select e.emp_id, e.first_name, count(*)
from employee e join
     tasks t
     on e.emp_id = t.emp_id
group by e.emp_id, e.first_name
having count(*) > 1;
```